# With only npm scripts, how do I replace templateURL with the template contents

Tags: angularjs, npm

Given an angular component:

```
(function () {
angular.module("components", [])
    .component("hello", {
        controller: helloController,
        controllerAs: "vm",
        templateUrl: "hello.html"
    });

function helloController() {
    var vm = this;
    console.log('Hello World.');
}
})();
```

How do I replace templateUrl: "hello.html" with template: "Hello" in a npm build.

I see lots of gulp, webpack, and grunt examples for angular templatecache, but I don't see a way to do this with just npm scripts.

I have the rest of the build process working with npm scripts, I just can't find an npm module that does this with a node command.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-html2js

Comment: If you use bundlers like webpack, then `template: require('hello.html')` is also possible.

Comment: ng-html2js does work on a single file and answers the question, wondering if there's another option that integrates with the way uglifyjs works.  Again ng-html2js does solve the problem I had.